# Tables Relation in database

Tags: sql, database, database-design

can I have three tables in my database and link them to each other like this?is it correct?
[image: this]

Comment: Except for "Yes" and "We don't know your requirements, so we can't say if it's correct", what answers are you looking for?

Comment: Although I generally tend more to "No", I fully agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever, to answer this properly, one has to know your requirements.
However, I _assume_ that this goes into the direction you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: IndexCards is a place to store my factors Information ,I want to Specified which user paid which factor and also get this information ,for this, I related IndexCards and Users table but i think may be I can just relate IndexCards to orders and relate orders to user and then use a view.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can set up your data this way.

No, it is probably not a good idea *if* orders.userId is supposed to be the same as orders.IndexCards.UserId.  Unless you need the redundancy for a good reason, it is better to have the link in only one place.

Of course, if orders.userId has nothing to do with the corresponding IndexCards.userId, then your data model is fine.

Comment: I agree with the general comments. Given the inputs, this is as good an answer as could be provided.

Comment: If there is a good reason for the column to appear in both tables (maybe `idfromIndex` is nullable, but the rule is that if it's not null, the user IDs should match), then a superkey in Index and a foreign key reference in Orders can enforce that constraint.

Comment: Thanks all for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You have an anomaly in your db. The anomaly that I've found is in the table named ***Orders***. Since ***IndexCard*** Table has that column(*idfromUsers*), you should delete it from that table(*Orders*) and removed its relationship to **User** table.

This means that **orders** has a relation to **IndexCards** and **IndexCards** has a relation to the **Users**.